# Visual Studio giving Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 error when trying to perform any database operation

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

"An unexpected error occurred in the .NET Framework Data Provider for Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0. Please contact the provider vendor to resolve this problem."
 is the actual error message. I am not sure when this error started but I have recently reinstalled VS2010 on this machine due to a HDD upgrade OS and registry etc... still the same as before. If anyone knows what could be causing this I would really appreciate any help.